# How to use d3 Update Selection to draw a sparse matrix

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to draw a matrix based on this example: http://bl.ocks.org/ianyfchang/8119685.
In my matrix, each element represents a ping RTT value from row[x] => column[y], e.g. if server 0 pings server 1 and returns 100ms, then in matrix node[0][1] = 100, of course to visualize networking status, i will fill green, yellow or red in each cell depends on corresponding RTT.

In this case, not every server pings all other servers, so the data I got is not a full mesh, mathematically speaking, it is a sparse matrix, most of the elements is null, data looks like this:

```
src       dest       RTT
server0   server1    100
server150 server10   80
server100 server100  600
...
```

I also have a full list of all servers, I draw all servers name as row and column labels, then covert each record's src, dest to index of server name in server name array.

Here is the problem, if I pass cooked (cooked means i have converted src and dest server name to their index in server list array) sparse matrix to d3, it only draws cells if there is a ping record, to let d3 draw all cells even there is no data, I need to create a full mesh matrix. After I read the introduction of d3's update, enter and exit selection, I think I may achieve in this way:

1. create a dummy full mesh matrix, let d3 draw all cells;
2. update d3.selectAll("cell") with my real matrix, so d3 automatically updates those dummy cells with real ping RTT value.

Here is my code, however it doesn't work:( does anyone know why? I have a feeling that I should control how my real matrix join the elements, but i don't know how to use the key function in .data().

```
var svg = d3.select("#matrix")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// create a dummy matrix and a dummy matrix
var dummy = [];
for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < servers.length; ++j) {
        var n = {};
        n.x = i;
        n.y = j;
        dummy.push(n);
    }
}

var heatmap = svg.append("g").attr("class", "g3")
    .selectAll(".cellg")
    .data(dummy)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.y * cellSize; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.x * cellSize; })
    .attr("class", function (d) { return "cell cell-border cr" + (d.x - 1) + " cc" + (d.y - 1); })
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return d.Item3 === undefined ? "white" : d.m_Item3 >= 5000 ? "red" : d.m_Item3 >= 2000 ? "yellow" : "green"; })
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("cell-hover", true);
        d3.selectAll(".rowLabel").classed("text-highlight", function (r, ri) { return ri === (d.x); });
        d3.selectAll(".colLabel").classed("text-highlight", function (c, ci) { return ci === (d.y); });

        d3.select("#tooltip")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px")
            .select("#value")
            .html("<p>Source: " + servers[d.x] + "</p>" + 
                  "<p>Dest: " + servers[d.y] + "</p>" +
                  "<p>RTT: " + (d.m_Item3 === undefined ? "N/A" : d.m_Item3 + "ns") + "</p>");

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
        d3.select(this).classed("cell-hover", false);
        d3.selectAll(".rowLabel").classed("text-highlight", false);
        d3.selectAll(".colLabel").classed("text-highlight", false);
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
    });

// next, update the update section.
heatmap.data(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I make it works but I dont know why, how the key function works.
To make it work i need to add same key function when join data.

When create full matrix using dummy matrix:

```
.data(dummy, function (d) { return d.x + ":" + d.y; })
```

Then when join with real matrix:

```
.data(matrix, function (d) { return d.x + ":" + d.y; })
```

I still don't know what is key function and why it should return string? Is key function equal to column name when do join in SQL? Data only get joined / updated if key function returns same string?